# Building customized data set from American Community Survey data?

Tags: data, census, united-states

I am trying to create a database in SQL Server with a customized dataset containing census information from the American Community Survey content available online. I want to show a granularity in my dataset and would like to download **blocks & census tract** level data of USA for 5 or 3-year timeframe ranging from *[2009-2013]*. I tried several methods to download both blocks & census tract level information. I could not get my hands on a data that would let me create tables and import values to them from the downloaded files.

I downloaded the **block** level data present in the PostgreSQL database section mentioned on the following link

- http://www.justicemap.org/data.php

and got one 15GB file in the FILE format. Then, I tried to download a block group level data for USA from the link mentioned below

- https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html

and that gave me a collection of gdb related files. After which, I followed a couple of video and pdf tutorials to download content similar to this and got a lot of data with tons of label names with no reference. Could someone please help me obtain a good dataset in a usable format that contains block or census tract level information.

Comment: Perhaps worth a look: https://github.com/leehach/census-postgres

Comment: Looks like a pretty good link. I will try to work with it. Thanks :)